# How to web3 "encodeFunctionCall" a payable function?

Tags: web3js, payable, web3js-v1.x, encoding, encodefunctioncall

I want to encode a call for `mint() payable` with a `msg.value` of 8 ETH.

My code:

```
web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({
    type: 'function',
    name: 'mint',
    payable: true,
    value: web3.utils.toWei("8", "ether")
}, [])
```

I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Help?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `inputs` field as per the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctioncall).

So, assuming no parameters :

```
web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({
    type: 'function',
    name: 'mint',
    payable: true,
    inputs: [],
    value: web3.utils.toWei("8", "ether")
}, [])
// returns: 0x1249c58b
```

You can omit the fields : `payable` and `value` they are irrelevant to generate the abi encoded function call. So :

```
web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({
    type: 'function',
    name: 'mint',
    inputs: [],
}, [])
// returns: 0x1249c58b
```

Without parameters, this is exactly the same as:

```
web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature("mint()")
// returns: 0x1249c58b
```

Comment: But if I omit the `value` field, how do I set the `msg.value`?

Comment: The result of `encodeFunctionCall` is basically what you will use to set the field `data` of your tx. It seems like you beleive that `encodeFunctionCall` is used to actually send a valid tx, is that so ?